# Customized memory management with sbrk

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, memory-management

Following is the code for a simple `malloc` implementation. A linked list is initiated with a head and tail pointer for memory management. Now in the function, there is only a single call implemented when the list is uninitialized, where the list's head is initialized. Once I return the underlying pointer to `main`, the program gives `segmentation fault`. On the other hand, the following `test` function with almost the same parameters except for the complicated handling of linked list computes correctly and displays the result. Can anyone please tell what am I missing here?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef struct Items{
  size_t size_of_object;
  size_t free;
} Items;

typedef struct Node{
  void *ptr;
  void *next;
  Items Item;
}Node ;

typedef struct LinkedList{
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
} LinkedList;


LinkedList memory_list;

void *salmalloc(size_t size_of_object) {
  if (memory_list.head == NULL) {

    memory_list.head = sbrk(sizeof(Node));
    memory_list.head->ptr = sbrk(size_of_object);
    memory_list.head->Item.size_of_object = size_of_object;
    memory_list.tail = NULL;
    memory_list.head->next = NULL;
    memory_list.head->Item.free = 1;

    return memory_list.head->ptr;    
  }
}

void *test(size_t size) {
  void *p = sbrk(size);
  return p;
}

void main(){
  char *p = NULL;
  char a = 'B';
  p = salmalloc(sizeof(char));
  *p = a;
  printf("%c\n", *p);

}
```

Comment: `if (memory_list.head == NULL) `  Where is this initialized to NULL?   And why show code that works?  Why not show the code that doesn't work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the `salmalloc` function does not work.

Comment: `On the other hand, the following test function with almost the same parameters except for the complicated handling of linked list computes correctly and displays the result.` So does the function you post work or not?

Comment: `void test` does work but `salmalloc` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues:

1. You haven't initialized `memory_list`.
2. `salmalloc` is missing an `else` part and since there is no `return` it will return random garbage in this case.
3. You need to check the return value of `sbrk`, it may fail (but `salmalloc` looks like work-in-progress anyway, isn't it?).
4. You need to check the return value of `salmalloc`, it may fail.

Here's a version that works on my system:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef struct Items{
        size_t size_of_object;
        size_t free;
} Items;

typedef struct Node{
        void *ptr;
        void *next;
        Items Item;
}Node ;

typedef struct LinkedList{
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
} LinkedList;


LinkedList memory_list = { 0 };

void *salmalloc(size_t size_of_object) {
        if (memory_list.head == NULL) {
                memory_list.head = sbrk(sizeof(Node));
                memory_list.head->ptr = sbrk(size_of_object);
                memory_list.head->Item.size_of_object = size_of_object;
                memory_list.tail = NULL;
                memory_list.head->next = NULL;
                memory_list.head->Item.free = 1;

                return memory_list.head->ptr;
        } else {
                return NULL;
        }
}

int main(){
        char *p = NULL;
        char a = 'B';
        p = salmalloc(sizeof(char));
        if (p == NULL) {
                printf("Allocation failed.\n");
                return 1;
        }
        *p = a;
        printf("%c\n", *p);
        return 0;
}
```